# Vampire movie-probably from the 80's

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

I saw this on TV in either the late 80's or early 90's. There are unfortunately only a few scenes that stick with me.

In one a vampire is in a room when suddenly UV lights come on, implying that they were harmful to him (I seem to recall another person in the room wearing sunglasses who wasn't as distressed).

In another scene near the end a blonde woman 'stakes' the vampire villain from behind (not sure if the woman was also a vampire, but I suspect she was).

In a third scene just before the end credits the vampire villain is being moved in a box, his body propped upright- when as a result of being jostled the stake falls out of his body, suggesting he would come back to life.

The movie was in colour, any dialogue was in English, fairly certain it was made at least early =-mid 1980's.

Comment: I don't recall any scenes but there certainly vampires with sunglasses in 1983 the Hunger https://youtu.be/7a6YFwC2zKA trailer and iconic music https://youtu.be/244qvxxy0N0

Comment: @lucasbachmann -no, the Hunger is a fairly well-known movie with widely known stars, I'm pretty sure the one I'm looking for is much more obscure.

Comment: Vampires okay with UV light reminds me of [Ultraviolet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_(TV_serial)) but it's a bit late, and they didn't use stakes.

Comment: @DavidW And Ultraviolet ended very differently.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly 1989's **Nightlife** starring Maryam D'Abo, Keith Szarabajka and Ben Cross; she's a vampire who comes back to life in Mexico. Ben Cross is the vampire in love with her and Keith is the doctor she consults. You can watch it [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NkoZ3SewuJc).

[IMDB entry](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097980/)

Comment: Trailer at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4Zi2aZ6C2Y in case the full film goes down. It was a 1989 TV film, not to be mistaken with the 1989 film  *[Night Life](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097972/)* (also known as *Grave Misdemeanours*) about a mortuary worker nerd who is pursued by zombie bullies.